# Create an array from id's from divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

On my page I've got many div elements which have the same class:

```
<div class="item" id="lorem">Asdf</div>
<div class="item" id="ipsum">Asdf</div>
<div class="item" id="dolor">Asdf</div>
```

Now I would like to save the id from every div to an array. It should then look like this:

```
$array = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"];
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the each() function of jQuery and iterate over each div to get the id and push it into an array.

```
var $array = [];
$('div').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $array.push(id);
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mokjL6b/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here item is your class name

```
var x = $('.item').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(x);
```

jQuery.map() function

Answer (score 0):

You can get id of div in array many ways

```
var IDs = [];
$(".item").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
console.log(IDs);
```

or

```
var ids = $('.item').map(function(index) {
    return this.id; 
});
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: first one is array and second  is object

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="item" id="lorem">Asdf</div>
        <div class="item" id="ipsum">Asdf</div>
        <div class="item" id="dolor">Asdf</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var res = Array();
                $('.item').each(function(index,`obj`){
                   res.push(obj.id);
                });
                console.log(res);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```